Openstack setup on AWS ec2 instances
i'm new to Openstack and i need to do experimentation and setup Openstack to test different distribution of it in order to find out which the best distribution for a highly available environment, scalable and specially that suits the best setting up a solid Kubernetes cluster on top of Openstack for dev/stage cluster. I've followed the official documentation but it seemed very advanced or complicated somehow. can you please help me with guidance or anything that helps on how to setup Openstack on aws using ec2 instances etc .. ?
Expectations: Being able to deploy Openstack cluster on EC2 instances using different distributions for proof of concept purpose.
